# How to create test classes that can be used in both Android tests and unit tests?

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing

I often find myself duplicating the exact same set of test classes such as mocks or helpers for both Android tests `/androidTest` and unit tests `/test` when writing tests for an application module.

For example, I have some static functions that help me set up mocks quickly in `/test/MockUtils.java` However, I cannot reuse this helper class in any of my Android tests because they do not share the same class path - `/androidTest` vs `/test`.

I've thought of creating a new module that only contains test resources. However, this idea won't fly because the Android Gradle plugin refuses to depend on an app module.

> project testCommon resolves to an APK archive which is not supported as a compilation dependency.

Is there any other way to create test classes that could be reused in both Android tests and unit tests?

Comment: More here: [Sharing code between unit tests and instrumentation tests on Android](http://blog.danlew.net/2015/11/02/sharing-code-between-unit-tests-and-instrumentation-tests-on-android/), [Share code between instrumentation and unit tests](https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/#/c/238184/1/app/build.gradle)

Answer (score 6):

NOTE: This is a theorized solution, one that I have not tried.

Step #1: Create a `testSrc/` directory in your module for which you are trying to set up the shared testing code.

Step #2: Put the shared code in that directory (with appropriate subdirectories based on Java package).

Step #3: Add the following closure inside your `android` closure in your module's `build.gradle` file:

```
sourceSets {
    androidTest {
        java.srcDirs <<= 'testSrc'
    }

    test {
        java.srcDirs <<= 'testSrc'
    }
}
```

What this should do is tell Gradle for Android that `testSrc` is another source directory for Java code in the `androidTest` and `test` sourcesets.

Comment: I had to modify your solution because leftShift does not work for some reason. I had to redeclare the paths instead `test {
            java.srcDirs =[ 'src/test','testSrc']
        }` Can you edit your solution so that I can accept it?

Comment: @SomeNoobStudent: What were your specific symptoms with the left-shift operator? I just created a new project, followed the steps in my answer, did the Gradle file sync stuff in Android Studio, and I didn't get any build errors. I even was able to run tests, albeit with an empty `testSrc/` directory.

Comment: I'm on `IntelliJ 14.1.4/Plugin 1.2.3/Gradle 2.4-all` and using `<<` has 0 effect - IDE does not highlight path green and classes within it are ignored, not allowing me to reference them in my tests.

Comment: @SomeNoobStudent: Hmmm... I'd like to find a syntax that doesn't force you to hard-code the existing path, in case that changes. I can reproduce your "IDE does not highlight path green" effect on Android Studio 1.2.2. If you could, try `java.srcDirs=[java.srcDirs[0],'testSrc']`. That gives me a green result.

Comment: @CommonsWare java.srcDirs=[java.srcDirs[0],'testSrc'] worked for me as long as testSrc is located at MODULE_NAME/testSrc. If trying to place it under MODULE_NAME/src/testSrc (to keep it with the other source code), I had to use java.srcDirs=[java.srcDirs[0], 'src/testSrc'] or java.srcDirs=[java.srcDirs[0], 'src/testSrc/java'] if the your code is located at testSrc/java (which is how test/androidTest are structured). I haven't played around to figure out how to reference MODULE_NAME/src in build.gradle w/o hard-coding

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but as @SomeNoobStudent mentioned, I have the same issue with leftShift, java.srcDirs =[ 'src/test','testSrc'] works for me.

Answer (score 3):

Based on CommonsWare's solution and https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=181391, the correct way to add an additional class path is to use the `+=` or `<<=` operators.

```
sourceSets {
    androidTest {
        java.srcDirs <<= 'testSrc'
    }

    test {
        java.srcDirs += 'testSrc'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution described in the blog below helped me.

http://blog.danlew.net/2015/11/02/sharing-code-between-unit-tests-and-instrumentation-tests-on-android/

I put my shared test code into src/sharedTest/java . Then I added the following code to build.gradle:

```
<pre>
android {  
  sourceSets {
    String sharedTestDir = 'src/sharedTest/java'
    test {
      java.srcDir sharedTestDir
    }
    androidTest {
      java.srcDir sharedTestDir
    }
  }
}
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best approach for now is to create shared gradle-module as described in [this article](https://blog.danlew.net/2022/08/16/sharing-code-between-test-modules/).

Just create a module (e.g. `sharedTest`) and use it as `testImplementation` and `androidTestImplementation`.

The solution with shared sources folder is not working in the modern versions of Android Studio.